# Replacing a special character in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a simple string like this, `let string = "123½";` and I want to replace it.

I've already tried `string.replace("½","0.5")`

I'm not exactly what is happening here, but maybe it's because it's a special character?

Comment: You didn't describe what's actually happening (or not happening)

Comment: Assign the result back to string `string = string.replace("½",".5")` because `String.replace()` creates a new string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.replace` doesn't modify a string; it returns a new string. Try:

```
const replaced = string.replace("½","0.5");
```

Comment: Replace with `.5` so you won't add another 0 to the number.